# Creating an object array of two value arrays dynamically – application: highcharts dotnet

Tags: c#, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm hoping to get a quick solution to this.

Here is a snippet of the code that works when creating a series:

```
  Series SeriesABC2 = new Series
            {
                Name = '#' + HakuAlueet[1],
                Data = new Data(
                    new object[]{ 
                            new[] {  300, 440 },
                            new[] {  400, 540 }
                            }),
                PlotOptionsArearange = new PlotOptionsArearange { Visible = true, LineWidth = 0, FillOpacity = 0.3 },
                Type = ChartTypes.Arearange
            };
```

Now the plan is to make this dynamic creating the values in the object "new[] {  300, 440 }, new[] {  400, 540 }" inside .net C#. I'm quite new to C# so I'm not quite sure of the naming convention, but I seem to need to make an array object of an two value arrays. How would I go about this?

I've tried countless ways of managing this but just haven't found a solution that would be acceptable to dotnet.Highcharts. Thanks!

Comment: `new object[,]`? it looks like a very bad idea to make an array of type `object` to me

Comment: Well, this is from the original example file that actually works. :)

Comment: Can you include an example of something you tried that didn't work, and how it didn't work?

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you are trying to acheive here, is it possible you need to make your own class which you can make an array of?

Comment: @hatchet, the examples of hasn't work are quite numerous, but I have serious problems with debugging since it gets stuck in the dotnet library.

Comment: @Sayse -- I'm unsure if this is required. As I understand, all I need to do is create an object array of bivariates, or a list containing lists of two values which then transformed into an array and then into an object.

Comment: It may well be all you require but actually using the data out of the list will be a nightmare as you'd have to cast it every time etc

Comment: @Sayse I'm just really, really hoping to get it working in anyway possible. If I understand correct, casting isn't a true problem since it's done only once/twice per page render - granted I'd love a direct input to array and then push to the Series Data property.

Comment: I'm still unsure of what you are trying to do sorry, if your trying to set arrays then you can do `Data[0] = new object[]{a,b}` but this assumes there will be at least 1 element in the array etc

Comment: @Sayse Well the basic idea is that I can input the numbers by hand in this format. The problem is feeding from a datatable. What I don't know is how to get from a SQLreader > Datatable > Array?? > Object[] since multiple parameters just won't come out in the required format. With this I cannot/don't know how to use object[]{a, b} since I have to feed the dynamic data from a datatable, datarow or a list.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the solution, but the final output through the translator is "data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2], ...]" in java.

When I try, I often end up with [[5, 6, 8, ...], [2, 3, 2, ...]], ie. I would need to transpose the feed so instead of two times X rows I have X number of two rows.

Comment: Wibin, its unrelated but that seems to be what your real question is, you should try posting a new question about how to translate data or read data in that format

Comment: @Sayse, well that format would be html jscript, which would be extremely time consuming to create dynamically through .NET. That's why they have created the Dotnet.Highcharts that I am now trying to work.

Comment: I still mean use the same technologies, just asking how to parse the data correctly instead of transposing it once you've received it

Comment: @Sayse, ah yes now I got it. This is my question. How to feed the data, preferably through the best method, and I've tried everything, including transposing which would be suboptimal. I just can't get it to work no matter what method I try. The Object usage example in the question is by the original developer of the plugin. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] books= source.Select(a => a.bookName).ToArray();
object[] visits = source.Select(a => (object)a.Visits).ToArray();

DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
                 .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Bar,
                                        Width = 900 
                  }).SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions {
                       Bar = new PlotOptionsBar {
                                     ColorByPoint = true,
                                     DataLabels = new PlotOptionsBarDataLabels {
                                                          Enabled = true }
                                     }
                 }).SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = books,
                 }).SetSeries(new Series
                         {
                             Data = new Data(visits),
                             Name = "User Book Visits"
                         });
lb_chart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();
```

Here source contain data where I am querying some dynamic content. This is working and hope this will also help you.

Comment: i am displaying Google analytic data in this chart where user can see which book was visited how many time... i have var object named source which contains the list of books name and their visits (within a specific duration ).  i declare two arrays 1)books 2)visits now i added this to the series where i set data= visits and categories=books..so when it rendered by browser it shows the book name and its visits by displaying a bar. i just created my account few minutes ago and i don't have permission to publish screenshot here..